# Best way to implement AdWhirl in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, singleton, adwhirl

What is the best way to implement AdWhirl in iPhone project?
- Will we create a singleton object for handling AdWhirl and use it through out the app.
- Or will we create each AdWhirl object in every screen (UIViewController) we want to add AdWhirl in.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.adwhirl.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want a different ad in every view controller you have, you should use a singelton, and add the ad UIView each time you're entering a new UIViewController.

I can't recall if adWhirl provide it for you, but if not, you should animate the ad View out in case no ads are available.

Answer (score 2):

you can see AdWhirl tutorial and implement in your project

https://code.google.com/p/adwhirl-with-iad/downloads/detail?name=AdWhirl_pro.zip&can=2&q=